# How to convert character half size (1 byte) to character full size in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I want convert character half size to character full size as:

- a(1byte) -> a(2byte)
- 2 half size space --> 1 full size space

I try to function StrCov in VB excel but it don't work.

Comment: Are you referring to Unicode for a "full size", 2-byte character vs a Local Code Page character as "half size" which could be 1- or 2-bytes? In either case, post the exact code you tried, and what result you got in order for someone to be better able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `StrConv` function using `vbWide` as the conversion. I believe the system locale must be properly set to an East Asia locale.

[StrConv Function on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264628.aspx)

Comment: I tried the example below but it don't work

Function convertString(inputStr As String)
    
   convertString = StrConv(inputStr, vbWide)
   
End Function

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes even the system locale is set to use the East Asia locale and you need to explicitly specified the locale id,which is 1041 for Japanese.

```
strResult = Strings.StrConv(strExample,VbStrConv.Wide, 1041)
```

This fix applied for the error stating following as well.

```
VbStrConv.Wide and VbStrConv.Narrow are not applicable to the locale specified
```